# Analysis proof on bounded function using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let f be continuous on the closed interval x ∈ [a, b]. Assume that for each x ∈ [a, b],
there exists y ∈ [a, b] so that |f(y)| ≤ 1/2 |f(x)|.

Problem:  Show that there exists a sequence (xn), n∈N with xn ∈ [a, b] with |f(xn)| ≤ |f(a)|2^(−n) ∀n ∈ N

So, I have been trying to solve this by induction, and I can see that the base case comes for free, since if look at f(a), we can simply choose our sequence to begin with x1 so that |f(x1)| ≤ 1/2 |f(a)|.

But I'm having trouble showing the inductive step: that is, to show if we assume the case is true for k, how do we show it for k+1? Can I somehow use Boltzano Weirstrauss to my advantage, since the sequence is bounded, then I know there is a convergent sub sequence?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using the given condition, you can for $x_1$ have $x = x_1$ and choose a $y = x_2$ so you get

$$|f(x_2)| \le \frac{1}{2}|f(x_1)| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, using what you got of $|f(x_1)| \le \frac{1}{2}|f(a)|$ in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$|f(x_2)| \le \frac{1}{2}|f(x_1)| \le \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}|f(a)|\right) = \frac{1}{4}|f(a)| \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

I hope this shows how you can use this idea to prove the requested statement by induction.

Comment: Ok, that's a lot simpler than I thought. But suppose now I had to show that there is an x in the sequence for which f(x) = 0. Now should I use Boltanzano theorem that says, if a sequence is bounded, there must exist a convergent sub sequence? I think I would try to prove by contradiction, but this I also find difficult.

Comment: @Sylvestaro Since $f$ is continuous on a closed set, it's bounded. As such, you could use the [Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano–Weierstrass_theorem) to prove there's a convergent sub-sequence. However, I don't believe it proves the sequence you're constructing is that convergent sub-sequence. Instead, proof by contradiction is actually not that difficult. As a bounded, continuous function on a closed set, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, all values between the bounds exist in the set. Thus, if the min $\le 0$ & max. $\ge 0$, you're done. ...

Comment: @Sylvestaro (cont.) Otherwise, you have the min. (call it $m_1$) & max. (call it $m_2$) are either both negative or both positive. However, if you let $x$ be $x_1$ if $|f(x_1)| \lt |f(x_2)|$, else have $x$ be $x_2$, then the property there's a $y$ where $|f(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|f(x)|$ gives a contradiction. I hope this makes sense. If not, since comments are not really an appropriate place for this, I suggest you consider asking a new question so I and/or other people can give you more detailed answers & other feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For every $x_k$ in the interval there exists an $y$ such that $|f(y)| \le \frac 12 |f(x_k)|$

Let $x_{k+1}$ equal the $y$ associated with $x_k$

$f(x_1)\le \frac 12 |f(a)|$

Suppose $|f(x_k)| \le 2^{-k} |f(a)|$

$|f(x_{k+1})| \le \frac 12 |f(x_k)| \le \frac 12 (2^{-k} |f(a)|)$ by the inductive hypothesis

$|f(x_{k+1})| \le 2^{-k-1} |f(a)|$